# CVE Parsing file information

Tags: c++, http, parsing, feed

Good morning,

I want to write a small tool (possible with Java, C/C++ ???) that queries the messages on https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/index.html and filters only certain relevant messages.

My questions:
1. Which format is the best one for parsing data? In the textfile, for example, all the information is arranged together. So I think a filter for searching  specific headers and specific lines will not work.

2. How do I get the information from one of the files locally on my PC or on a server?
3. How do I read and filter this information?

Comment: The [CVE Search project](https://www.cve-search.org/about/) has got information on parsing and a downloadable JSON file containing all the CVEs, which might be the best place to start.

Comment: Is there a possibility to write a Google Doc Spreadsheet makro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend the JSoup Java library for fetching and parsing web pages. You can use a syntax very similar to jQuery for extracting data from the pages you've fetched.

Comment: Maybe Python is a better solution? I can download the csv-list and filter items.